# React Native is not managing one state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app in React Native. This app send a API call using axios to my backend server that response a JSON with 2 fields, ie: Todos and Internal_info.

```
{ "todos": [{ //Data here }],
"int_info": [{ //More data here }]
}
```

Then, my app takes those fields and puts each one in their respective state. The state of the Todos is refreshing properly, and if it refreshes, it re-renders the components, and everything is fine. However, with my internal information, it’s a different story. I call it internal information because the user is not allowed to see it through any component.

When I input the information into the state, everything seems to be working fine. I can even display the information on the screen using some test  components. However, internally, the functions that should work with that information still appear to have the initial state: an empty array.

Here is the i think is the relevant code about this job:

```
export function TheComponent(){
const [int_Info, setInt_info] = useState([]);
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

const getInfo = async (devicePk) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await getDigest(devicePk) // This is my api call, works fine
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Digest: ", response.data)
          const newTodos = response.data.todos;
          const newInt_info = response.data.int_info;
          setInt_info(newInt_info);
          setTodos(newTodos);
        })
        .then(() => {
          setIsLoading(false);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error Digest: ", error, JSON.stringify(error));
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };}
```

Then I use a DeviceEventEmitter.addListener() to handle an event where I utilize the information from the state with a handler. However, it appears that the state it captures is the initial empty array, rather than the current state containing all the information accessible through the components. Do you have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Thank you! If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Greetings!

UPDATE:
I Migrated DeviceEventEmitter.addListener() to NativeEventEmitter, still bugged :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe DeviceEventEmitter is deprecated. Test it with NativeEventEmitter
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript

Comment: Ok, I did that migration, but problem persists :(